# Why run time error UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION is triggered although I catch the exception?

Tags: exception, abap

I expect the following program to output an error message (via `WRITE`), but actually it triggers the run time error `UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION` (short dump) at the time of `RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE`:

```
REPORT.
CLASS lcx_exception DEFINITION INHERITING FROM cx_static_check.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS main.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE lcx_exception.  "<===== HERE, run time error UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
START-OF-SELECTION.
  TRY.
    NEW lcl_app( )->main( ).
  CATCH lcx_exception INTO DATA(ex).
    WRITE: / 'Exception:', ex->get_text( ).
  ENDTRY.
```

Comment: Nice question based on my comment to another one! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to add [**`RAISING lcx_exception`**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapmethods.htm) (eventually more exception classes may be listed here) to the method declaration, so that the exception is automatically propagated to the calling procedure (and caught, hopefully) when it occurs:

```
REPORT.
CLASS lcx_exception DEFINITION INHERITING FROM cx_static_check.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS main RAISING lcx_exception. "<==================== HERE
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE lcx_exception.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
START-OF-SELECTION.
  TRY.
    NEW lcl_app( )->main( ).
  CATCH lcx_exception INTO DATA(ex).
    WRITE: / 'Exception:', ex->get_text( ).
  ENDTRY.
```

Note that you can't list the exception classes which inherit from the root class `CX_NO_CHECK`, directly or indirectly, because these exceptions are propagated implicitly. Only exception classes inheriting from `CX_STATIC_CHECK` and `CX_DYNAMIC_CHECK`, directly or indirectly, need to be indicated after `RAISING` for being propagated. Those 2 root classes may also be indicated to propagate all exception classes.